# How to remove a KEY from a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary called `d` as mentioned.

```
Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    d["dog"] = 1;
    d["cat"] = 5;
```

Now if I want to remove the key `"cat"` I can't use the `Remove()` method as it only removes the corresponding value associated and not the key itself. So is there a way to remove a key?

Comment: just call the remove method of dictionary: `d.Remove("cat");`

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.remove?view=net-5.0)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The Remove() method actually deletes an existing key-value pair from a dictionary. You can also use the clear method to delete all the elements of the dictionary.

```
var cities = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
    {"UK", "London, Manchester, Birmingham"},
    {"USA", "Chicago, New York, Washington"},
    {"India", "Mumbai, New Delhi, Pune"}
};

cities.Remove("UK"); // removes UK 

//cities.Remove("France"); //will NOT throw a an exception when key `France` is not found.
//cities.Remove(null); //will throw an ArgumentNullException

}

cities.Clear(); //removes all elements
```

You can read this for more information https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-dictionary

Comment: `Remove` does not throw if the key is not found (only if the key is null).  If the key is not in the dictionary then it returns false.

Answer (score 7):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.remove?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2_Remove__0_) is a bit unclear here, you are right:

> Removes the value with the specified key from the
> Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.

If you scroll down a bit you see a better wording:

> The following code example shows how to remove a key/value pair from a
> dictionary using the `Remove` method.

There is never a key without a value in a dictionary(even a `null` value would be a value). It is always a [`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=net-5.0). So you can simply use `Remove` to remove the cat-entry.

```
d.Remove("cat"); // cat gone
Console.Write(d.Count); // 1
```

Comment: Very nice answer